# eval() function in php not working

Tags: php, eval

i have a little problem with eval.

here is my code:

```
$postbit = $template->output('posts_list_index'); // output string: $postslist it's ok

eval('echo $postbit;'); // output string: $postslist (?)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What does `echo $postbit;` outside of `eval()` produce? I don't quite get why you're using `eval()` here.

Comment: im using eval to make a plugin engine and template engine.
this is the result of echo $postbit: '$postslist'

Comment: @TimPost: The term "postbit" makes me suspect this may be related to the MyBB forum software (which uses that term to refer to the widgets surrounding a post, like the "Reply" button). As I recall, its template engine does work something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think in `eval()` function you can able to replace string with values. Please refer https://www.php.net/eval.

and the solution for your's is:

```
eval("$postbit = ".$template->output('posts_list_index'."); "); 

echo $postbit ;
```

try this one.. I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Eval requires that you escape your `$`:

```
eval('echo \$postbit;');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Javadewd's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419867/404115) is correct. I prefer using double quotes instead of single quotes. [PHP Manual](https://php.net/string) states

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.